# Issues deploying playN android app to phone in netbeans

Tags: android, netbeans, playn

I have been struggling with this setup for a while now. I have been trying to setup a project with the playN library on netbeans using the tutorial [here](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2012/05/24/Using-Netbeans-712-with-PlayN-13.aspx).

The project builds fine and will run as a desktop java app and web app. I can build the project as an android app, but it will not deploy to my phone (I have a Galaxy Nexus) or to an AVD.

The log seems fine...

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building playndemo Android 1.3
------------------------------------------------------------------------

[android:deploy]
C:\android\platform-tools\aapt.exe [dump, xmltree,     C:\Users\Kyle\Documents\NetBeansProjects\playndemo\android\target\playndemo-android-    1.3.apk, AndroidManifest.xml]
N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
E: manifest (line=2)
A: android:screenOrientation(0x0101001e)=(type 0x10)0x0
A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x1
A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="1.0" (Raw: "1.0")
A: package="com.kashank.demo.playndemo.android" (Raw: "com.kashank.demo.playndemo.android")
E: uses-sdk (line=7)
  A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x6
  A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0xb
E: application (line=8)
  A: android:label(0x01010001)=@0x7f030000
  A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f020000
  A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
  E: activity (line=9)
    A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x1030007
    A: android:label(0x01010001)=@0x7f030000
    A: android:name(0x01010003)="playndemoActivity" (Raw: "playndemoActivity")
    A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0xa0
    E: intent-filter (line=13)
      E: action (line=14)
        A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw: "android.intent.action.MAIN")
      E: category (line=15)
        A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
Waiting for initial device list from the Android Debug Bridge
Found 1 devices connected with the Android Debug Bridge
android.device parameter set to usb
Device 0A3C0D3C02008015_samsung_GalaxyNexus found.
Successfully uninstalled com.kashank.demo.playndemo.android from     0A3C0D3C02008015_samsung_GalaxyNexus
Found 1 devices connected with the Android Debug Bridge
android.device parameter set to usb
Device 0A3C0D3C02008015_samsung_GalaxyNexus found.
Successfully installed     C:\Users\Kyle\Documents\NetBeansProjects\playndemo\android\target\playndemo-android-1.3.apk    to 0A3C0D3C02008015_samsung_GalaxyNexus

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building playndemo Android 1.3
------------------------------------------------------------------------

[android:run]
Found 1 devices connected with the Android Debug Bridge
android.device parameter set to usb
Device 0A3C0D3C02008015_samsung_GalaxyNexus found.
Attempting to start com.kashank.demo.playndemo.androidplayndemoActivity on device     0A3C0D3C02008015 (avdName = null)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 5.695s
Finished at: Sun Sep 02 17:15:58 EDT 2012
Final Memory: 6M/15M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Another oddity is that netbeans does in fact see my phone, I can initiate a screen shot from within netbeans of my phones home screen.

Comment: Have you checked the settings , applications screen whether app is present. Looks like its deployed but not starting.

Comment: @nandeesh you mean the settings in the phone? Yes i just verified, but the application is not listed under the list of installed apps

Comment: You could pull out C:\Users\Kyle\Documents\NetBeansProjects\playndemo\android\target\playndemo-android-1.3.apk and then run the command adb install ndemo-android-1.3.apk and check if you are getting any errors

Comment: @nandeesh well it's not ideal, but that does work. I can manually extract and install the apk and it launches ok. Thanks for the help!